# Format function doesn't work in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to run the script below in SQL 2008 R2 but I'm getting an error (`FORMAT is not recognized`). I'm thinking the SQL Server installed is 2008 R2. Any idea to convert the script to work in SQL Server 2008 R2? Thanks in advance.

```
declare @sample table (dt datetime)

insert @sample values ('2017-10-09 20:04:00.000')
insert @sample values ('2017-10-07 00:55:22.000')
insert @sample values ('2017-10-16 15:52:34.000')
insert @sample values ('2017-10-06 03:09:31.000')
insert @sample values ('2017-10-06 19:56:09.000')
insert @sample values ('2017-10-06 06:36:39.000')
insert @sample values ('2017-10-05 16:19:14.000')

select 
    s.dt,
    DATEADD(hh,8,s.dt) AS dt_plus_8,
    FORMAT(CAST(DATEADD(HH,8,s.dt) AS DATETIME), 'hh tt') as TIME_HOURLY
from
    @sample s
```

Desired result:

```
DT----------------------DT_Plus_8--------------Tim_Hourly
----------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-09 20:04:00.000--2017-10-10 04:00:00.000--04 AM
2017-10-07 00:55:22.000--2017-10-07 08:00:00.000--08 AM
2017-10-16 15:52:34.000--2017-10-16 23:00:00.000--11 PM
2017-10-06 03:09:31.000--2017-10-06 11:00:00.000--11 AM
2017-10-06 19:56:09.000--2017-10-07 03:00:00.000--03 AM
2017-10-06 06:36:39.000--2017-10-06 14:00:00.000--02 PM
2017-10-05 16:19:14.000--2017-10-06 00:00:00.000--12 AM
```

Comment: `FORMAT` is a **new function** introduced in SQL Server **2012** - it doesn't exist in earlier versions, and there's no easy "workaround" for it, either. You need to change your code to work *without* `FORMAT`, e.g. by using the appropriate `CONVERT` function call and the suitable style for the `CONVERT` function: [CAST and CONVERT in T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you

```
SELECT  
    s.dt,
    DATEADD(HOUR,8,s.dt) AS dt_plus_8,
    FORMAT(CAST(DATEADD(HH,8,s.dt) AS DATETIME), 'hh tt') as TIME_HOURLY
    ,RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(HOUR,8,s.dt)) % 12 ),2) 
        + ' ' 
            + CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(HOUR,8,s.dt)) > =12 
                THEN 'PM' 
                ELSE 'AM' 
              END AS TIME_HOURLYv2
FROM
    @sample s
```

Comment: @Jov Glad to help. If you can mark this as the accepted answer (tick) and up vote that would be appreciated.